# When should I use yield* vs yield in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I want to call another saga from a saga.

The saga is of course a generator function, and is asynchronous.

Should I ever user `yield *` or should I always use `yield`?

```
function* mySaga({ payload: { id, name } }) {
    yield myOtherAsyncSaga(); // when to use yield *?
}
```

Comment: Well as written, your `mySaga()` generator will return just one result from the other generator, and then it'll be done.  The point of `yield *` is to effectively delegate to the other generator, and continue to return *all* its results until it's done. The delegating generator can yield its own values before and after that.

Comment: So `yield` is behaviourally the same as `yield *` if the generator only returns a single result?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes; it would be pretty easy to verify that experimentally with a couple of trivial test functions.

Comment: It depends a lot on how the generator is consumed. If the consumer can recursively handle yielded generator objects, it might not make a difference at all.

Comment: Generally, `yield` would be identical to `yield*`in Redux, since `yield` will yield out the iterator, and Redux magic will make it work, just like if you have yielded out a promise. `yield*` just means you handle the iterator yourself, right there, while `yield` lets Redux handle it for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The saga is of course a generator function, and is asynchronous.
> Should I ever user yield * or should I always use yield?

Completely to answer a question, at first it is necessary to understand as saga, middlewares, process manager and generator functions generally work. In fact `redux-saga` implements two sides: middleware for redux store, which intercepts and injects custom actions, and [async process manager](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler.js), which has own tick callback domain and helps with perform async action.

Next, every client-implemented saga function is just [effect creator](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/io.js). In fact client saga function is implemented such way, that it actually does not do anything, but effect creation - `call`, `take`, `put`, etc. Also, saga is not sync or async by nature - it just delegates some behavior to saga process manager, and it perform requested actions - for example, waiting promise.
Of course, you can manually perform promise/async handling in client saga, but such actions will fall from saga event cycle.

So, `redux-saga` internals wants from client saga just to be [an iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), which returns appropriate effects and maybe store some information in closure activation context - in case of `while(true)`- like saga processes. So, there is no use case in `redux-saga`, where `yield *` is mandatory, since `yield *` is just re-delegation of subsequent iterator to upper level.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: always use `yield*` for performance and correct type resolution in TS

If you are on JS land, `yield` gives the middleware a Generator and the middleware will automatically iterate it. If you use `yield*`, you are iterating the generator and yielding all the items to the middleware.
There is no big difference in this case, except that hitting the middleware is slower.

When using TypeScript, things change a bit: `yield` means that the iteration of the generator will happen in the middleware and because of that our types will be incorrect. If instead we use `yield*`, the iteration will happen on our scope and TS will be able to detect the proper types.

There is a small TS library that illustrates this better: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-redux-saga